# Conditional Cumsum of one dataframe, dependent on a different dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, cumsum

I have two data frames that are exactly the same size, and I want to cumsum everything to the left of a specific cell on one dataframe assuming the value is the same in the other. If the value changes in the other dataframe, I would want to reset and set that as the endpoint to stop summing from the dataframe.

Summing Table:

| Summing | 01-Jan | 02-Jan | 03-Jan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| Y | 250 | 100 | 150 |
| Z | 300 | 300 | 300 |

Conditional Table:

| Condition | 01-Jan | 02-Jan | 03-Jan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Y | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| Z | 1 | 2 | 3 |

Expected output:

| Expected | 01-Jan | 02-Jan | 03-Jan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 100 | 200 | 300 |
| Y | 250 | 100 | 250 |
| Z | 300 | 300 | 300 |

Tried original cumsum function and it didn't work really well, trying to implement a new definition to possibly mark the places where the cumsum stops. Was thinking I might be able to use melt to find the changing points but unsure how that would benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `df1` and `df2` your inputs, you can temporarily reshape your DataFrame to run a [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
out = (df1
 .set_index('Summing').stack()
 .groupby(['Summing', df2.set_index('Condition').stack()])
 .cumsum()
 .unstack().reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
  Summing  01-Jan  02-Jan  03-Jan
0       X     100     200     300
1       Y     250     100     250
2       Z     300     300     300
```

Comment: Appreciate it, I was wondering, if I had to multiply the two sections of where the cumsum breaks, how would I do that universally? For example row 0 would just take 300, row 1 would multiply 250 * 250, row 2 would multiply 300 * 300 * 300.